# I'm new to angular and trying to get an input after every (onchange) event and send this input to a set method. see code below

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

After searching throw the documentation I found a clear warning not to use ElementRef for direct DOM access. I't seems the Renderer2 is the prefered way to do so but I couldn't figure out how to use it.
Please Help!

---

// add-shipper.component.html

```
<section>
    <h2>Add Shipper</h2>
    <!-- after each key typing, the DOM data is passed to the appropriate method -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" (onchange)="setShipperName(@input())"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" (onchange)="setShipperEmail(@input())">
    <button (click)="addShipper()">Submit</button>
</section>
```

---

// add-shipper.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Shipper } from 'src/app/modules/shipper';
import { ShipperService } from 'src/app/services/shipper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-shipper',
  templateUrl: './add-shipper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-shipper.component.css']
})
export class AddShipperComponent implements OnInit {
  public shipper: Shipper

  //ShipperService is injected here using it's @Injectable annotation
  constructor(public shipperService: ShipperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shipper = new Shipper();
  }

  public addShipper(): void {
    this.shipperService.addShipper(this.shipper).subscribe((addedShipper) => {
      this.shipper = addedShipper;
    });
  }

  public setShipperName(name: string): void {
    this.shipper.setName(name);
  }
  public setShipperEmail(email: string): void {
    this.shipper.setEmail(email);
  }
```

---

Comment: For what purpose you want to use ElementRef or Renderer.

Comment: What doesn't the above code do that you'd like it to do? I am failing to see what problem you're having.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input and https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview. TIP use [(NgModel)]. Angular is mainly relation view (the .html) and model (the variables in .ts)

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what do you want to do, but i can see some problems in your code:
1) I think you want to use '(change)' event not '(onchange)' .
2) If you want to get reference to the DOM node, use ViewChild decorator.
Something like this will work.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Shipper } from 'src/app/modules/shipper';
import { ShipperService } from 'src/app/services/shipper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-shipper',
  templateUrl: `
<section>
    <h2>Add Shipper</h2>
    <!-- after each key typing, the DOM data is passed to the appropriate method -->
    <input #myInput type="text" placeholder="Name" (onchange)="setShipperName(@input())"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" (onchange)="setShipperEmail(@input())">
    <button (click)="addShipper()">Submit</button>
</section>

`,
  styleUrls: ['./add-shipper.component.css']
})
export class AddShipperComponent implements OnInit {
  public shipper: Shipper

  @ViewChild('myInput') input: ElementRef;

  //ShipperService is injected here using it's @Injectable annotation
  constructor(public shipperService: ShipperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shipper = new Shipper();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.input)
  }

  public addShipper(): void {
    this.shipperService.addShipper(this.shipper).subscribe((addedShipper) => {
      this.shipper = addedShipper;
    });
  }

  public setShipperName(name: string): void {
    this.shipper.setName(name);
  }
  public setShipperEmail(email: string): void {
    this.shipper.setEmail(email);
  }
```

Comment: That is what i'm trying to avoid. See below documentation comment :
Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.

Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.

Answer (score 0):

To capture every input you should use keyup event.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" #d (keyup)="setShipperName(d.value)"> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" #e (keyup)="setShipperEmail(e.value)">
```

It will capture every input user type.

Better way to use [(ngModel)] which will capture every input change and reflect it also.

Instead of onchange, use (change)

Comment: You can use `(input)="setShipperName($event.target.value)"` also